# QGIS changing layer colors

Tags: qgis, layers, style, color, change

I'm having a problem with several QGIS projects. I style and format the vector layers, save, and when I reopen the project another day the formats are changed. All the vector layers appearing in **blue or red.**

The layers are stored on OneDrive, I thought it could be due to something related to this but it doesn't happen to me in all projects. Also I could be working with the same projects for days and nothing like this happen, then, suddenly one day all the styles are gone.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

We are talking about vector layers.

I save the styles in the project, and save the project but since this started to happened I also export some styles to save time next time this happens again. At first I thought that the problem was related to several using the same file at the same time from Drive, but it happened to me in a project in which this does not happen

Comment: Which file type are we talking about? Does someone else have access? Are the affected layers styled differently from those which don't change?

Comment: How do you style your layers? Styles are properties of the project and should not change. Since they are on OneDrive, is anyone else accessing the same projects?

Comment: Does this happen exclusively after you close and re-open the project, by any chance?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: When you wrote "I style and format the vector layers, save..." do you mean that you saved the layer? Styles are saved into a project, so you must save the project instead.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and it exactly happens for same people. We're using QGIS, and for a team of 4-5 people, the styling of their QGIS project turns completely red and blue every day. We've updated their QGIS version, but the issue persists. The projects are saved in OneDrive SharePoint.

Comment: Erik asked about files types.  Vector isn't specific enough I would think.  Are they shapefiles, file geodatabases, geopackages or something else.  Styling can be stored in a geopackage.  Another thing you might note is how you've set up One Drive, including syncing and local storage.  In my experience I had a lot of issues keeping my project's files stored on One Drive or Sharepoint, especially if they were file geodatabases.    I can't imagine adding multi-user to that.  In our setup local files were used in the projects and when done uploaded to Sharepoint for others/future use.